# Command line args within <<EOF in a shell script?

Tags: shell, sftp

My current requirement is passing the commands to be executed in SFTP box dynamically to the shell script. My script will contain command sets, username, directory as arguments. Is it possible to achieve this? Currently we tried with sending parameters with files, but for n customers n files will be there. Can we use sftp `<<EOF` syntax in order to pass the command line arguments from shell script to `<<` command?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

My suggestion is to keep all the customer records in a single csv file, you can extract the value as:

```
export a=`cat $BATCH_PROCESSES/input/$v_DateTime/$filename|head -$i|tail -1| awk -F ',' '{print $1}'`
export b=`cat $BATCH_PROCESSES/input/$v_DateTime/$filename|head -$i|tail -1| awk -F ',' '{print $2}'`
export c=`cat $BATCH_PROCESSES/input/$v_DateTime/$filename|head -$i|tail -1| awk -F ',' '{print $3}'`       
export d=`cat $BATCH_PROCESSES/input/$v_DateTime/$filename|head -$i|tail -1| awk -F ',' '{print $4}'`       
export e=`cat $BATCH_PROCESSES/input/$v_DateTime/$filename|head -$i|tail -1| awk -F ',' '{print $5}'`
```

Comment: May i know the reason for flagging this to delete please?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. My requirement is how to redirect the values obtained from suggested step to sftp command? Please help me with it?  because sftp << whether i can use normal commands like $1 or variable 'a' within sftp<< command?

Comment: @Sushma you have said that you are using file for that. Is there any limitation to put all the records in a file and fetching them 1 by 1 in the loop ?

Comment: i will agree with the approach. I'm new to shell scripting could you please help me how to pass these values to sftp <<, within << mode it will take the values as static ryt? is there a way to pass dynamic values within <<?